# How can I install Ubuntu using the Alternate disk from USB-stick?

Tags: usb, iso, installation

I created the stick with Unetbootin. The stick boots fine, but after language selection the installer says that CD-ROM is not in the drive. How can I get around that?

The desktop disk works fine, but I can't use it.

I cannot use usb-creator-gtk since it gives me Segmentation faults for some reason... So I have to stick with unetbootin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Startup Disk Creator in System --> Administration

Comment: It gives me a Segmentation Fault when creating the stick :(

Comment: Use an older (or newer) iso like 9.10 or 10.04 or 10.10 to create it

Comment: 10.04 worked fine, but 10.10 just gives segmentation faults. Wtf?

Comment: Probably a bug in 10.10 :)

Comment: ps that's why I always choose LTS :)

Please mark the answer as right and upvote if you've found this correct :)

Comment: Multiple bugs on Startup Disk Creator (usb-creator) are reported: 572611, 875758, 859539.

Answer (score 1):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Comment: **The tool recommended in that post fails with a segmentation fault.** That's the whole point of the question!